# How do I return an error from a loop in a controller?

Tags: sql, node.js

I show show the SQL structure, the data that i'm trying to insert, and the code. Then I expose the problem.

It's a simple e-commerce project. And the problem is related to the Order creation (POST)

SQL structure:
[image]

Data JSON format:

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "role": "administrator",
        "userId": 63
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "added": 2,
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Le Classique",
            "price": 5
        },
        {
            "added": 5,
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Le Classique",
            "price": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

NodeJS controller function:

```
exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
   const formData = req.body

   const newOrder = {
      user_id: formData.user.userId,
      date: new Date()
   }

   const newOrderItems = formData.items

   try {
     await db.query(
       "INSERT INTO orders SET ?", newOrder, (err, results) => {
         if (err) {
             res.status(500).send("Erreur d'écriture des données")
         } else {
             newOrder.id = results.insertId

             for (let i = 0; i < newOrderItems.length; i++) {

               let orderItems = {
                 orders_id: newOrder.id,
                 items_id: newOrderItems[i].id,
                 quantity: newOrderItems[i].added
               }

               db.query(
                 "INSERT INTO order_items SET ?", orderItems, (err, results) => {
                   if (err) {
                     // throw an error? and cancel everything?
                   }
                 }
              )
             }

             res.status(201).send({
               order: newOrder
             })

         }
     })

   } catch (err) {
       return next(err)
   }
 }
```

My code is working BUT i have a problem with the error when i try to enter a false item id. For example the first item as an ID 6, but there is no item with that id in the database. So he skips that item from the loop (with probably an SQL error that we don't see) and continue with the other loop (and register the next one with sucess).

If i put `throw new Error("This is the error text")` The server crash

After every loops, It sends the 201 status. But i would like to return an error in that case and cancel the order. Do you thing it is possible?

Thanks

---

EDIT for the comments:
(results console.log)

```
Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: undefined,
  _callSite: Error
      at Pool.query (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
      at exports.create (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/controllers/Orders.controller.js:89:32)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
      at module.exports (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/middlewares/Auth.middleware.js:17:13)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
      at Route.dispatch (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at /home/jer/projets/coco/coco/backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22,
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO orders SET ?',
  values: { user_id: 63, date: 2020-09-04T15:01:16.405Z },
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the temp array for maintaining the errors coming from SQL while adding items and after a loop, you can check the length of an array for sending the response. Since you are using callbacks then we have to maintain a separate counter to check whether all requests came back or not

Below the sample code.

```
    exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
const formData = req.body

const newOrder = {
    user_id: formData.user.userId,
    date: new Date()
}

const newOrderItems = formData.items

try {
    await db.query(
        "INSERT INTO orders SET ?", newOrder, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send("Erreur d'écriture des données")
            }
            newOrder.id = results.insertId
            const errData = [];
            let queryCounter = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < newOrderItems.length; i++) {

                let orderItems = {
                    orders_id: newOrder.id,
                    items_id: newOrderItems[i].id,
                    quantity: newOrderItems[i].added
                }

                db.query(
                    "INSERT INTO order_items SET ?", orderItems, (err, results) => {
                        // keeping track of records tried
                        queryCounter++;
                        if (err) {
                            errData.push(err);
                        }

                        // check if all callback came back
                        if (queryCounter === newOrderItems.length) {
                            if (errData.length) {
                                return res.status(500).send({
                                    message: 'Failed to insert items',
                                    errors: errItems
                                });
                            }

                            return res.status(201).send({
                                order: newOrder
                            });
                        }

                    }
                )
            }
        })

} catch (err) {
    return next(err)
}
```

}

Suggestion: shift to promises instead of using callbacks, they give tricky situation like this.

Comment: Hello, i think you have a good idea; But something's wrong. I tried with your code and it doesn't wait to have an error before ending the loops ... So the errItems array is always empty for him (at the IF condition)

Comment: yeah just noticed that your inserting code is in callback, ideally, your success response is also going without check, so we can add returning statement into callback also

Comment: Yes i've just added else {] around the res.status(201). But still don't know how can I enter in the error (500) you added if there is one (or more) error in the array

Comment: Thanks, but now the results.insertId is undefined. I think I can't receive the insertId. I don't have it if i consolelog results

Comment: what you are getting in results while doing console.log

Comment: i edited the original post and added the console.log from results. i don't have insertId in results. I just can have it with my original function but It wont work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220987/discussion-between-nitzy-and-jer).

Comment: updated the code for answer, Avoid using callbacks, they are pretty old and gives problem like this, instead use promises

Comment: Thanks it works great! You mean this code is using promise? Or I have to check out how Promises works? (i'm not familiar with Promises yet but if i have to edit that code with promises, I will do it)

Comment: Yeah this is callbacks, you have to change the mysql module first to use promises